# Webform Conditional fields showing by default

Tags: webforms

I am using the [Webform Conditional](http://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) module to control visibility of some webform components until a checkbox has been ticked.

I found recently that the conditional fields were showing by default (they were not doing so previously).

To add to my confusion, the same set of related fields worked just fine on some nodes but not on others.

Then just as suddenly as the problem appeared, it vanished and my conditional fields began working as expected again.

The site is soon to be LIVE and it be really bad if this problem unexpectedly returns.

**Can anyone offer some opinion as to why that happened, especially if it has happened to you before, and how I can make it more stable, please?**

Comment: Would love to know if and how you managed your conditional fields to work @sisko

I've enabled the webform conditional module, but cannot see any difference between now compared to before i enabled it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kine456: My problems with webform conditional were very occasional. I mean sometimes they were there and other times they just disappeared.

I am also using [webform template](http://drupal.org/project/webform_template). On the templates, the conditional fields always worked but not so on the webforms inheriting from the template.

Thankfully, conditional fields have been built into webforms. I downloaded and currently use [version#7.x-4.0-alpha6](http://drupal.org/project/webform). No problems to report so far