# How to make all webform types collapsed by default?

Tags: webforms

I just installed a [Weboform Conditional](http://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) module as per @PreritMohan recommendation.

Is there a way to make Textfield, textarea, select option, email, number, date, file types Collapsed by Default ?

I am running Drupal 7.19, webform 7.x-3.18 and webform_conditional 7.x-1.0-beta1

Also, what values should I put in the Options text area? (Key-value pairs MUST be specified as "safe_key|Some readable option". Use of only alphanumeric characters and underscores is recommended in keys. One option per line. Option groups may be specified with . <> can be used to insert items at the root of the menu after specifying a group.)

SImilarly, what should I put in the Values field under the Conditional Rules section? (List values, one per line, that will trigger this action. If you leave this blank, this component will always display.)

Comment: If you don't understand the module's documentation, file a support request in the module's issue queue.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickKenny

I've tried that in the past but have never received a response...

Comment: Well, Drupal maintainers have a lot to do, and they volunteer their time to provide support; a lot of times, you just need to do what you can to figure it out yourself.  In this case, though, the module's project page states that the author is willing to provide Drupal consulting services for a fee; that's one option you can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let me recommend you use [Weform 7.x-4.0-alpha6](http://drupal.org/project/webform). It has conditionals built into it. Webform Conditional is a great module but I had [problems](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51230/webform-conditional-fields-showing-by-default/62803#62803) with it.

Options, for select components, take the following format:

```
mr|Mr
ms|Miss
mrs|Mrs
doc|Doc
```

The in-built webforms conditionals are very simple and intuitive. Just add a condition and it will display an interface enabling you to hide/show a component when another component is/is-not a certain value.

Comment: Thank you @sisko

Will webform conditional enable me to hide all the form elements until the very first checkbox is selected? Or can it only hide certain element types?